# Is there a way to add a filter to the Entity Framework layer to exclude "IsArchived" records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have records marked up as "IsArchived". I am looking for an expedient way to exclude these records from a current MVC3 / EF3 web application.

Is there a way to add some kind of "IsArchived" filter to the EF layer. In my case I have a seperate Model project with tables/views represented as POCO entities, and the mappings contained in the CSDL and SSDL files.

Huge thanks for any assistance.

EDIT:

I am using "ObjectContext" and not "DbContext", mainly due to the Data Modelling tool that I am using. This tool creates the context and POCO files.

I am wondering whether I can edit this context file like the following:

```
    public ObjectSet<StdOrg> StdOrg
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_StdOrg == null))
            {
                _StdOrg = base.CreateObjectSet<StdOrg>("StdOrg");
                // new line below. Got cast error tween both sides.
                _StdOrg = (ObjectSet<StdOrg>) _StdOrg.Where(r => r.IsArchived == false);
            }
            return _StdOrg;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some form of abstraction (such as a `UnitOfWork` & `Repository`) over your `DbContext` and `DbSet`s?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. No I do not, and I have just been reading some interesting views on this subject. I thought that Repository was a no brainer recommended route, but it seems not. Now there is a strong school of thought that with modern ORMs, there is less of a need for another abstraction layer, so my expedience, may not be a bad idea of all. I have just found that I am using "ObjectContext" and not "DBContext", and am trying to put filters into this context file. See EDIT.

Comment: Here's my thoughts on the `Repository` pattern - in your case it would mean you could easily add filtering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110890/not-using-repository-pattern-use-the-orm-as-is-ef/17473500#17473500

Comment: I gave you another mark !!! Very interesting. Thanks. However I am a little nervous about altering different code routines to use this interface. At present I use the EF directly in the controllers via LINQ. Yes, It may have been better to use a repository pattern, but I guess I am here now, under a time pressure, and will look to integrating this repository pattern later, while a filter addition to the ObjectContext should, in theory, just implement the filter for my whole application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2012/01/25/a-smarter-infrastructure-automatically-filtering-an-ef-4-1-dbset.aspx

Basically a filtering DBSet implementation that the example basically shows being used for Soft Delete. We use it without issue in our App.

However we are using DBcontext so not sure how this would work with Object Context or how it could be adapted

Comment: I have marked this as an answer since it is a good end point, however not quite right for ObjectContext. What I ended up doing was creating a "Mapping Condition" in the Model which works well. However the Conditional Property can then not be used as a property so updates to this column need raw DDL. I believe NHibernate is more advanced than EF in filtering. Thanks.