# Generic data access code to stored procedures to return Enumerable<t>?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, refactoring

Instead of repeating the same ADO.net code with a different Enumerable, I want to make it more generic and reusable.

I have the following ADO.Net code to return a collection of objects:

```
public static IEnumerable<TasCriteria> GetTasCriterias()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            com.CommandText = "IVOOARINVENTORY_GET_TASCRITERIA";
            var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapt.SelectCommand = com;
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(dataset);

            var types = (from c in dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                         select new TasCriteria()
                         {
                              TasCriteriaId = Convert.ToInt32(c["TasCriteriaId"]),
                              TasCriteriaDesc= c["CriteriaDesc"].ToString()
                         }).ToList<TasCriteria>();

            return types;
        }

    }
```

Model:

```
 public class TasCriteria
    {
        public int TasCriteriaId { get; set; }
        public string TasCriteriaDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What code is repeating? Show an example of the similar invocation, which should be covered by the generic implementation. Also show what you have by now and where you stand.

Comment: Do all your models contain a `CriteriaId` and a `CriteriaDesc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to extract your specific code outside of your main method.

In example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetCriterias(
                            string storedProcedureName,
                            Func<IEnumerable<T>> enumerateMethod)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = conn;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
        var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapt.SelectCommand = com;
        var dataset = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(dataset);

        return enumerateMethod(dataset.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

If your stored procedure requires parameters, you can overload your function as:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetCriterias(
                        string storedProcedureName,
                        Func<IEnumerable<T>> enumerateMethod,
                        SqlParameter[] parameters)
```

Using this code, you can define methods that matches de `Func<>` signature.

```
public static IEnumerable<TasCriteria> EnumerateTasCriteria(DataTable table)
{
    return 
        (from c in table.AsEnumerable()
        select new TasCriteria()
        {
            TasCriteriaId = Convert.ToInt32(c["TasCriteriaId"]),
            TasCriteriaDesc= c["CriteriaDesc"].ToString()
        }).ToList<TasCriteria>();
}

public static IEnumerable<DetailCriteria> EnumerateDetailCriteriaCriteria(
                                            DataTable table)
{
    return 
        (from c in table.AsEnumerable()
         select new DetailCriteria()
        {
        DetailCriteriaId = Convert.ToInt32(c["DetailCriteriaId"]),
        DetailCriteriaDesc = c["CriteriaDesc"].ToString()
        }).ToList<TasCriteria>();
}
```

Then, you can call your code as:

```
IEnumerable<TasCriteria> task = 
         GetCriterias<TasCriteria>("IVOOARINVENTORY_GET_TASCRITERIA", EnumerateTasCriteria);
IEnumerable<DetailCriteria> details =
         GetCriterias<DetailCriteria>("IVOOARINVENTORY_GET_DETAILSCRITERIA", EnumerateDetailCriteriaCriteria);
```

Comment: i'm still learning ...In terms of separating them up in class files...what would be good practice? Naming conventions?

Comment: This last question requires an specific answer itself, I think... In my opinion, this could be a good oportunity to apply [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

Comment: I was actually hinting that...All the examples of repository involve EF.

Comment: One small request, if I have parameters? How would I take that into account.

Comment: Ex: comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = criteriaId;

Comment: @Chaka what kind of parameters? For your stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, if I want to grab one tasCriteria by Id for example.

Comment: Updated answer. You can overload your signature to allow an array of parameters (or `List<SqlParameter`, or `IEnumerable<SqlParameter`, ...)

Comment: Btw, I have a bounty for this question if you have the time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813905/re-factor-my-dal-code-to-a-domain-driven-design-or-more-modern-design-c-3-5

Answer (score 1):

If your stored procedure returns column names matching exactly properties in your class, you can use reflection like this code. I'll leave an exercise to add parameters to the stored procedure for someone else. (by the way, this is untested code, I wrote it off the top of my head)

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetStoredProcedure<T>(string procedure) where T : new()
    {
        var data = new List<T>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            com.CommandText = procedure;
            var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapt.SelectCommand = com;
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(dataset);

            //Get each row in the datatable
            foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                //Create a new instance of the specified class
                var newT = new T();

                //Iterate each column
                foreach (DataColumn col in dataset.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    //Get the property to set
                    var property = newT.GetType().GetProperty(col.ColumnName);
                    //Set the value
                    property.SetValue(newT, row[col.ColumnName]);
                }

                //Add it to the list
                data.Add(newT);
            }

            return data;
        }

    }
```

So lets say you have a class like this:

```
public class TasCriteria
{
    public int TasCriteriaId { get; set; }
    public string TasCriteriaDesc { get; set; }
}
```

You would call the function like this:

```
IEnumerable<TasCriteria> criteria = GetStoredProcedure<TasCriteria>("IVOOARINVENTORY_GET_TASCRITERIA");
```

Comment: Sorry, how would you call it?