# Am I properly creating my interface for a partial DbContext class in EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am utilizing ASP.NET WebAPI 2 & EF6 for a very small project which utilizes AutoFac to inject my DbContext directly into my controllers.  I am *not* using a repository pattern as per Ryan's answer here: [NOT using repository pattern, use the ORM as is (EF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110890/not-using-repository-pattern-use-the-orm-as-is-ef).  To perform the injection, I went ahead and created an interface like so:

```
public interface IMoveGroupEntities : IDisposable
{
    System.Data.Entity.DbSet<HostEntry> HostEntries { get; set; }
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Then implemented the interface on a partial class which sits in conjunction with my generated entities like so:

```
public partial class MoveGroupEntities : IMoveGroupEntities
{
}
```

I have a sneaking suspicion I'm doing something incorrectly here as I feel like this line:

`DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;`

Shouldn't be needed, but it does appear to be necessary as "Entry" is used from within my scaffolded API controller.

Can anyone chime in here on a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can say about scaffolded code is: it works. It's not the best code architecturally. I fully agree with the link you quote, but that doesn't mean that the controllers should be in touch with EF artifacts directly (including `Entry`).

I think it's a mistake to replace one `DbSet` wrapper (repository) by another wrapper. The gist of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159814/861716) is: use the context (and `DbSet`s, etc.) directly in your code. That is: don't use wrappers. That is *not*: use contexts (etc.) *anywhere*. You're doing the exact opposite: you create a different type of wrapper in order to use EF anywhere. But it's a good thing that your gut feeling doesn't really like it.

I always prefer to keep action methods (MVC, Web API) small. Basically, I just make them call a service method. It's the service that deals with contexts and everything EF has to offer. These services may be in a separate assembly, but wherever they are, they are injected into the controllers by dependency injection and, likewise, they obtain their contexts by DI.

Comment: Thanks Gert--could you elaborate on the differences between repository and service patterns?  Do simply expose business logic from your service as opposed to simple CRUD operations?

Comment: For the really simple CRUD operations scaffolding code is sufficient and convenient (although so far I never used it, we use Breeze for simple data access). When it gets a little bit more complex (i.e. implementing a business use case) I always use service methods that I can test in integration test and that can also be used by other applications in the same suite.